# I am trying to inset the bottom face of an object but no circle is appearing?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, eevee-render-engine

[image]

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBztmFHkNQo, and I am trying to inset the face of the bottom, but when i try to inset the face no circle appears.

I can see the arrow and dotted line to the centre and the bar at the top shows that the thickness is changing. when I inset the top face it is visible but not when I do the bottom face.

I am up to 4:43 of the video.

here is the blender file : [image]

Comment: Hello please tell what minute of the video you're refering to and share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi, Jack, and welcome.  You're going to attract better answers if you try to save folks as much work as possible. It's too much to expect potential answerers to wade through an entire video with advertising, trying to guess what you mean by 'the face at the bottom'. Please illustrate your problem with a screengrab from your workspace, showing what is not working, and indicating the result you want to achieve.

Comment: @RobinBetts: That's a great moderator's post! I am glad you are now moderator too!! and of course you got a vote from me! ;) and quellenform as well ;)

Comment: Sorry if my question sounds stupid, but since you didn't provide any screenshots of your model or tell us where in the tutorial you are, I suspect it's the basic modeling of the stem. Is the bottom of the stem closed with a face or is it open? You can only inset a **face**, if the bottom is open and you've just selected a ring of vertices, you cannot **inset** anything, because there is nothing. Still, the tool will show the changing _Thickness_ values when you move the mouse.

Comment: sorry ill ad a screenshot

Comment: would you like a screen recording perhaps?

Comment: actually nevermind Gordon Brinkmann solved my problem, thank you

Comment: @Jackryan Glad to hear that, but actually an open bottom wasn't the problem in your mesh. When you select the edge loop, you select one of two that are in the same place (that's why you then only see selected vertices/edges without the bottom face being selected). An edge loop cannot be inset because it's not a face. This wouldn't happen if you were in _Face Select_ mode and selected the bottom face directly, then the inset would work, however you still have duplicate vertices on the edge. To get rid of them, select all with A, then M > _Merge_ > _By Distance_.

Comment: @Jack Thanks for the edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial invites you to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> click one of the edges around the bottom face, to select the edge loop of which it is a part. When you do that, it does not select the bottom face, which, when you are more experienced, will arouse your suspicions. (Somehow, you have selected the loop, but not the face.)

Jiggling one of the vertices in the loop reveals that there are double-vertices in it:

[image]

The outside loop won't inset, because it's blocked by the coincident inside loop. There is already an inset, of 0, perhaps left behind by a previous attempt.

When you 'cancel' an inset or an extrusion by right-clicking, it *does not cancel the generation of new geometry*; only the move. It just drops the new geometry in place.To cancel the whole operation, you have to undo, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

**TL;DR**

Select all, and <kbd>M</kbd> merge > 'By Distance'. That will weld all the coincident vertices together, so you can have another go.

Comment: Nice trick to reopen the question, when I wrote my comment with the solution the  question was still closed so I couldn't answer...  :D

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Sneaky... isn't it ? >8D  ...  Having torn a little bit of a strip off Jack, I felt honour-bound to reopen after his edit and request , and to guarantee him an answer. I should have paid more attention to the commentary and left it to you, sorry.....

Comment: No problem, I cannot wait forever until you stoop to re-opening the question. Time is money :D